# What's the "Private" directory in OS X for?

Tags: macos, disk-space

I was running OmniDiskSweeper today, and I came across something called "Private" using 3.9GB. It is listed directly under the root directory along with Users, Library, System, and Applications, so I am assuming it is something included with OS X itself. I'm just curious about what this actually is, because I don't remember seeing this before. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Mid 2012 15 inch MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.3 El Capitan

Comment: Have you tried googling some of the file names? the more unique the more chance of finding the cause.

Comment: @Mark I believe your proposed duplicate is more of a /private/tmp-related question, but ComputerScienceStudent's question here asks more of "what is /private for".

Comment: @Mark, "What's the “Private” directory in OS X for?" and "Why is /tmp a symlink to /private/tmp?" **are not** duplicate questions, not even possible duplicates IMPO.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate is an answer here - it could be expanded a bit but it is still the same answer

Comment: Not a duplicate. See the answer below. @Mark

Comment: I'm leaving this closed. OP - could you remove the imaged and restate what you don't get? Since you've already received and accepted an answer - keeping this closed to new answers is good for the site since it now points to the main discussion on what /private is and does.

Comment: @MrU I came here because this one of the tops hist on Google for this folder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

/private has been around for a *loooooong* time. Every Mac has it.

It is part of your Mac: the directory stores essential system files and caches, along with other databases that your system requires to operate.

---

I'll give a quick explanation contents of the folders /private/etc, /private/tmp, and /private/var, usually found in /private:

**/private/etc**

Data files for system use, configurations for various command line tools etc

**/private/tmp**

System logs, mostly

**/private/var**

More logs, databases for daemons, virtual memory swap file(s), sleep image etc.

---

In essence, deleting *anything* in this directory is probably not a good idea, save for a few files. If you do delete them however, some required essential files will get regenerated on startup.

It's probably a good idea to Google the **exact** full directory path of any system folders you intend to tinker with before actually beginning to experiment with stuff inside.

I hope this helps.

Comment: My app needs to store a file not accessible/readable by a regular user. Would `/private/etc/myfile` be a good place to store it?

Comment: @OrangePot I believe that /private is generally reserved for system use and probably shouldn't be used for concealing files from the user. You'd also need root access to write to /private. I'd recommend storing your files in /tmp, with root being the owner and permissions as 700 or rwx------ (only root can r/w/x)

Comment: What came into their mind? Things that are in `/private` actually belong in `/usr/local`, they don't? Well, I guess there is no turning back.

Comment: There's nothing incorrect about this answer, but IMO it does not address the actual question. Traditional Unix/Linux/BSD systems have actual directories at `/var`, `/etc`, and `/tmp` -- but on macOS these are just symlinks to equivalent directories inside `/private`. Your answer nicely explains what's in there and why that data exists, but it does not explain what `/private` itself is for or why it exists. The reader is left wondering: _What is the value of diverging from the norm?_

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://qr.ae/pKY59u) -- in the NeXTSTEP days, it was a way to store those directories locally in a netboot scenario.